# Field object and Line is overlapping/change its place in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have a design in crystal which has field object, line and again field object one by one. If the first field object data is character count is high, it push the below to move to other place. Please let me know if any solved it and thanks in advance

[Please refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdiVo.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should split the section into two: first one holds the first field, second one the line and the second field. The section will grow as its contained fields need more space.

Also refer to the quite extensive online documentation of Crystal Reports, there's also a dedicated chapter dealing with the overwriting problem you are facing: [Keeping variable length objects from overwriting each other](https://help.sap.com/viewer/dfc124becfa845ffa91b1e717b20e3ec/2020.1/en-US/476391e36e041014910aba7db0e91070.html)